# Problem with gestureResponseDistance in react-navigation v6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using `gestureResponseDistance` to increase the swipe back area, but it's not working, and it shows me `No overload matches this call.`

```
<HomeStack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        gestureResponseDistance: {vertical: 200, horizontal: 150},
      }}>
      <HomeStack.Screen
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Home',
          headerStyle: styles.header,
          headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitle,
        }}
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
      />
      //...........

</HomeStack.Navigator>
```

[image]

any clue what's the problem? or maybe solutions?

Answer (score 2):

`gestureResponseDistance` accepts a number in 5.x, not an object.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x/#the-gestureresponsedistance-option-is-now-a-number-instead-of-an-object

But I also see you're using `createNativeStackNavigator` which doesn't have this option. Only `createStackNavigator` supports `gestureResponseDistance`.